# Keeping SVN local copy clean - am I doing it wrong?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

It has been a while since I last used SVN. In my checked out local copy, `\myproject\`, there are subdirectories that my IDE generates like `\bin\`, but after checking out SVN has created `\trunk\`, `\branch\` and so on.

It looks slightly messy to me. I would rather all my files be separated from those subdirectories; is this the norm? And if not, is there anything I can do to change it other than dump all my own files into another subdirectory `\dev\`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`trunk`, `tags` and `branches`  are the standard Subversion *directories*. Good thing you didn't fill up your disk drive checking out the entire repo, and all branches too.

Subversion uses what is called [*Inter-File Branching*](http://www.ithound.com/abstract/inter-file-branching-practical-method-representing-variants-2120). All this means is that branches are literally directories in the repository instead of some sort of meta-data on the file. The advantages include visible branch names (you can easily see all branches via `svn ls`), the full meta-data capability of version control (you see who created a branch, when, and why, and from where), and it means branching an entire project and not a per file branch scheme.

Plus, like other version control elements, you can *delete* a branch without destroying it. This means you can delete obsolete branches (or if you prefer, move them to an obsolete directory) and the branches listed will only be current and active branches. You also have the ability to use *hooks* to control branching.

The disadvantages is that people will accidentally checkout all branches (and in Subversion case) all tags, and the main trunk which takes forever and clogs the user's disk. Another disadvantage is that syntax is a bit funkier for comparisons.

#### CVS syntax to compare the 1.34 branch to the 1.35 branch:

```
$ cvs rdiff -rBR_1.34 -rBR_1.35 $repo_name
```

#### SVN syntax to compare the 1.34 branch to the 1.35 branch:

```
$ svn diff http://svn.vegicorp.com/svn/branches/1.34 http://svn.vegicorp.com/svn/branches/1.35
```

You could shorten this with some environment variables:

```
$ REPO=http://svn.vegicorp.com/svn
$ svn diff $REPO/branches/1.34 $REPO/branches/1.35
```

But, you can still see it's a lot more typing. Instead of merely specifying two branch names, you have to specify two complete repository URLs.

Let's get back to your mistake: What you did was something like this:

```
$ svn co http://svn.vegicorp.com/svn
```

Because someone told you the repository was located at `http://svn.vegicorp.com/svn`. If I didn't know Subversion, I'd probably do the same thing. However, this checked out *the trunk* and all branches that were ever created, and all tags that were created. That could take forever to checkout and clog up your disk. If I did this with my repository, I would have about 3 or 4 terabytes of data on my 500 Gigabyte hard drive. You can see that would lead to some disk space issues.

If you want to checkout the trunk, you need to include that part of the Subversion URL in your checkout command:

```
svn co http://svn.vegicorp.com/svn/trunk
```

If you want to check out the 1.34.2 branch, you would include that in your Subversion URL in your checkout command:

```
$ svn co http://svn.vegicorp.com/svn/branches/1.34.2
```

Note that the URL not only includes the repository name, but also the branch or trunk you want to checkout.

You can also checkout a particular tag too. Let's say you want to checkout the 4.3 release:

```
$ svn co http://svn.vegicorp.com/svn/tags/4.3
```

If you want to see a list of all branches (or active branches if your site *trims* branches when they're obsolete):

```
$ svn list http://svn.vegicorp.com/svn/branches
```

Hope this clarifies your situation.